# After the user enters his name to log-in, a welcome message appears

Tags: c

We were tasked to make a program about "**After the user enters his name to log-in, a welcome message appears**"

This is our code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// forward references
int readline(char[]); // prototype
void welcome(char[]); // prototype
#define MAX_LINE 100
char userName[MAX_LINE]; // buffer for user name
main()
{
printf("Please enter your name: ");
readline(userName); // ignore returned value
welcome(userName); // say hello to login user
// ...........................
}
int readline(char strBuffer[])
{
int c, count=0;
while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
strBuffer[count++] = c;
strBuffer[count] = '\0'; // null terminated
return count; // #char in the line
}
void welcome(char name[])
{
printf("%s, you are welcome.\n", name);
```

After we passed this code, our adviser told us some comments (His reply):

> 1. Redefine the prototype of readline as:
>
>    `int readline(char strBuffer[], int maxbuf)`
>
>    Where maxbuf represents the size of the buffer.
> 2. Change the sample program to use the newly defined readline function and check whether the overflow phenomenom is resolved.
> 3. Write a function void beep(int n) which emits n audio beeps.

We are having a hard time understanding his comments. We would like some help, to understand what is he trying to convey in a simpler explanation. Thank you :'>

Comment: He means reimplement `readline` to accept a max-occupancy argument, then actually use it, to prevent the buffer overflow exploit that function currently allows. Once you change that function, the program using the old declaration will no longer compile, so fix that too (i.e. pass the size info as a second argument in those locations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int readline(char strBuffer[])
{
int c, count=0;
while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
strBuffer[count++] = c;
strBuffer[count] = '\0'; // null terminated
return count; // #char in the line
}
```

but you can overflow. How bit is the buffer? `readline` doesn't know. You should have `int readline(char strBuffer[], int maxbuf)`. This should look eerily familiar. There's a reason for that.

Normally we wouldn't have a `readline` like this, but just call `fgets()` directly.

```
if (!fgets(userName, MAXLINE, stdin)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading standard input");
    return 1;
}
size_t userNameLen = strlen(userName);
if (userNameLen == 0) {
    return 0; // Typically we don't complain about EOF; just exit.
}
if (userName[userNameLen - 1] != '\n') {
    fprintf(stderr, "User name too long");
    return 1;
}
userName[userNameLen - 1] = 0;
```

Eventually you'll have a completely different form of readline that stretches the buffer until the line fits, but you're not there yet. We make do with this kind of construction for now.